# Popstate won't work with page transition animations

Tags: ajax, browser-history, fetch-api, popstate

I'm using Fetch api with anime.js, the problem is in back and forward buttons, i can't include animations and properly remove old container and add new one...

function fetchPage(link, page) {
    let baseURL = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}`;

```
if (window.location.port) {
    baseURL += `:${window.location.port}`;
}

fetch(`${baseURL}/${page}`)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.text()
    })
    .then(function(html) {
        let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");

        anime({
            targets: '.big-text, .big-text__title',
            translateX: 500,
            opacity: [1,0],
            easing: 'easeInExpo',
            duration: 500,
            complete: (anim) => {
                document.querySelector('.column-wrapper').remove();
            }
        })

        setTimeout(function () {
            document.querySelector('body').insertBefore(doc.querySelector('.new-content'),null);
                $.getScript('js/separated.js');

                anime({
                targets: '.big-text, .big-text__title',
                translateX: [-500, 0],
                delay: (el, i) => 100 * i,
                opacity: [0, 1],
                easing: 'easeOutExpo',
            })


        }, 700);
    })


  window.addEventListener('popstate', function(){
          fetchPage(baseURL, location.pathname);
```

})

}

Comment: So i found solution         window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
            let baseURL = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}`;
            fetchPage(baseURL, location.pathname)
        })